# Notepad++ plus plus Highlight content - highlight newly added data automatically

Tags: editor, notepad++

In a given paragraph as below I have highlighted Tom with StyleToken1

My name is `Tom`. I live on Earth.

Now, when I add more content to the file I want `Tom` should be highlighted automatically as new occurrences come in file. Is there a way to achieve this.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could define a User Define Language. Language -> Define your Language...

- first tab: define some sane default for default text and background color,
- second tab: enter Tom int 1st group textbox, define some color via the Styler button, probably you want to select prefix mode
- Save As... (e.g. as Tom)

Now you can select Tom from the Language menun and occurrences of Tom should be colored as defined on the second tab.